# Google calendar API grantOfflineAccess() without a pop up

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth

We have been working on an app that requires access to a users google calendar. We have been using the `grantOfflineAccess()` method described in google api's documentation - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergrantofflineaccessoptions

However, the problem we are facing is that this opens a pop up and we need to do this via a redirect. Does anyone have any ideas todo this without a pop up showing up?

Safari and Firefox block pop ups and this does not really work well on safari on mobile.
I was able to find a GitHub issue for this https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/288 but I have seen other websites do this without a pop up. You can check zendesk & frontapp.com - both of whom take offline grant for the users signing in.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain which kind of app are you talking about? Are your referring to as Apps Script WebApp or to an Add-on or an extension? It is the user who runs the App and retrieves his own calendar or it e.g. the admin accessing other users calendars? Are the users all of the same Google domain?

Comment: I am talking about a web app that a user visits on a mobile via an app or in a browser client. The only way for a web / mobile app to get offlineGrant through googles API is to use the in-built method in `gapi` called grantOfflineAccess() and this method opens a pop up with no option to redirect users to another URL. I would want a redirect in place of a pop up

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access a users data is to have a user grant you permission to access that data.   This is done though [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth) a user is promoted to login to their google account then they are given a screen with the scopes of permissions that you are requesting.

There is no way around this.  YOu will always have to ask a user at lease once to grant you permission to access their data if you are requesting offline access you will be given a refresh token that you can use to request a new access token and access the users data when they are not online.

As for popups they shouldn't be displaying as popups they should be opening in a new browser window.

Comment: maybe you did not understand my question or I wasn't clear. The problem is not with the auth handshake or that I need to get the users grant. My issue is that I want to get the grant through a redirect URL or another method call that does not cause a pop up. Please read the GitHub issue here - https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/288 to understand my problem

Comment: Maybe I should be asking, could I for example, using the javascript library get a refresh token from this URL `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token code={AuthCode}&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&access_type=offline`